# Can't get a django-admin to start a new project. It's looking for an old project I deleted

Tags: python, django

I run the command `django-admin startproject LIMS`. I get the error

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'CMIRS'`
```

where CMIRS was an old project directory I deleted. Why is it looking for an old project? If it's a setting I've changed I can't remember where I've changed it. I have a database named CMIRS.

```
`[informatics@aib-biprod01 public_html]$ grep -R CMIRS *
mysite/mysite/settings.py:        'NAME': 'CMIRS',
Binary file mysite/mysite/__pycache__/settings.cpython-34.pyc matches`
```

Here is where CMIRS is seen in mysite/mysite/setting.py

```
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'CMIRS',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
    }
}`
```

Comment: What is your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable?

Comment: Where is that info located?

Answer (score 0):

run  `grep -r CMIRS *`  on the commandline. You'll see all the files where it still exists.

Comment: and you (double) checked `mysite/mysite/settings.py` if it is mentioned there?

Comment: 'NAME': 'CMIRS' refers to a database I have. I will also post that code above. Does that affect it? I'd rather not delete that project, because it's the only thing I've gotten working on my web server.

Comment: no, just the database name should be ok. Are you running `grep` from the folder where your mange.py is, or one up/down?   (btw, theres also a mention of the projectname in manage.py)

Comment: I ran it at /home/informatics/public_html. So one above manage.py. I don't understand what you mean in 'theres also a mention of the projectname in manage.py'

Comment: I mean in manage.py there is  `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings") `   but if `grep` didnt detect it, it is probably not there.

Comment: I'm running the grep command from / just to see if anything pops up. I'm new to Django, but not to programming. I'm just having a hard time making sense of the error.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did. Nothing is popping up. I'm going to uninstall and reinstall django tomorrow.

Comment: Okay uninstalled Django, then re-installed it. Made a project. Tried to migrate. Same error.

Comment: try `python manage.py startproject LIMS` instead of django-admin ...  ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/ )